# CLLocation Manager not updated when App is in Guided Access mode

Tags: ios, ipad, guided-access

I kept Guided Access for iPad app. When the app is launched it asks for user's current location using `CLLocationManager`.This is working under Normal mode and updates user current location. But under Guided Access, `popup ("Allow to access your location")` is not shown and `authorizationStatus` is always `kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined` and doesn't update current location of user . Couldn't understand what could be the problem.Searched a lot but couldn't find it.

```
ViewController.m :

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [appDelegate startLocation];
[self performSelector:@selector(CheckLocationManger) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
}

-(void)CheckLocationManger
{
    AppAppDelegate *appDelegate=(AppAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];


    if(![CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled])
    {
        UIAlertView *alert1 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Whoops we can’t find you!" message:@"Location services are disabled" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        if(activityIndictr)
            [activityIndictr stopAnimating];
        [alert1 show];


        return;
    }
    if([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled])
    {
        if([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]==kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied)
        {

            UIAlertView  *alert1 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Whoops we can’t find you!"message:@"Location services are disabled. You can fix this by going to Settings > Privacy > Location" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"  otherButtonTitles:nil];
            if(activityIndictr)
                [activityIndictr stopAnimating];
            [alert1 show];
            return;
        }
        if([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]==kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) //This is called 
        {

    [self performSelector:@selector(CheckLocationManger) withObject:self afterDelay:0.1];  

            return;
        }

    }

    if(![self connected])
    {

        UIAlertView *alert1 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Network Error" message:@"Please verify that you have internet connectivity" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        if(activityIndictr)
            [activityIndictr stopAnimating];
        [alert1 show];
        [alert1 release];
        return;


    }
    else {
        //continue further process

    }

}


AppDelegate.m

- (void)startLocation
{

    self.locationManager = [[[CLLocationManager alloc] init]autorelease];
    self.locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically=NO;
    [self.locationManager setDelegate:self];
    if([[[UIDevice currentDevice ]systemVersion] floatValue]>=8.0)
        {

          if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
                [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization]; //is executed but popup never displays 
            }

        }

        [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

}
```

Any suggestions would be helpful.Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

At very first set `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` or `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` in your `.plist`.

Add `CoreLocation.framework` and import in your class.h file -> `#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>` then set `CLLocationManagerDelegate` to your class.

Declare `@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager;`
Init locationManager and set default value to it.

```
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
self.locationManager.delegate = self;
self.locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO;
[self.locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation];
[self.locationManager setDistanceFilter:200.0f];
if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)])    // Or if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)])
    [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];                                      // Or [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

Implement `CLLocationMAnager` delegate method

```
#pragma mark - Location Delegate

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    NSLog(@"updated coordinate are %@", [locations lastObject]);
    CLLocation *currentLocation =  [locations lastObject];
    // Your code.....
}
```

Comment: We have already implemented everything like this.It works under Normal mode.But under Guided Access it doesnt work .No popup is displayed asking to access user location..What else has to be done. Plz help

Comment: try to delete and reinstall the app and try again and also read this document https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT202612