# Core location manger not asking user permission in ios9.0.2

Tags: ios, swift

I am using core-location manager to get user's location update, its working fine in ios8.x, but when I installed my app in ios9.0.2 it didn't ask for user permission to access his location.

I searched for this issue & all I found was that there is a new key added for ios9 "allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates" which needs to be set to yes, but as far as i understood this key is useful when we want to access location in background , & i am using user's location in foreground.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: may be you already allowed it? Are you sure that it's your first time running app? And is it work?

Comment: @sakshi, please Check in Device or Simulator, and you can see its already allowed, and if you want to allow again then, remove App and change date and Run app again then you can see its working. and ask permission.

Comment: @OrkhanAlizade yes app is running for the first time & i didn't allowed it earlier because no alert was shown.

Comment: @Mehul i checked it in device it didn't ask for permission, & when i check in settings->privacy->location none of the options (Always/Never) was selected for my app.

Answer (score 0):

@Sakshi Please refer answer in this [CLLocation Manager not updated when App is in Guided Access mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30912465/cllocation-manager-not-updated-when-app-is-in-guided-access-mode/30913257#30913257)

May be you have not set key in `info.plist`.

1. Delete application
2. Implement as above
3. And try again.